# django page redirect on success login

Tags: django, redirect

im not getting exactly.. actually on httpresponse redirect it show nothing.
actually on http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/ in show my login page 
now i want on correct login it will redirect to my index page.
dont the exact way.

```
def login(request):
    template = "../templates/admin/login.html"
    data = {
        }
    user = auth.authenticate(username='aa', password='bb')
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        template = "../templates/admin/index.html"

        auth.login(request, user)
     return HttpResponseRedirect("/login/index/")

    return render_to_response( template, data, 
                               context_instance = RequestContext( request ) )
```

thanx in advance.

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login

Comment: Looks right to me (assuming indentation is correct on your version). That would either throw a python error, redirect to `/login/index/` no matter what, or redirect on success. You say it's returning a blank page?

Comment: actually when i write http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/ it will automatically redirect to index page without showing the login page

Answer (score 1):

If you are being redirected automatically, then your indentation is off. You got unlucky and however you wrote your code didn't trigger an `IndentationError`.

My guess is you copy and pasted from the documentation and added to the code?

I'd check to make sure you don't have tabs and spaces mixed up.

Here's a fixed one that pulls information from the POST request.

```
def login(request):
    template = "../templates/admin/login.html"
    data = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST.get('username'),
                                            password=request.POST.get('password'))
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/login/index/")
    return render_to_response( template, data, context_instance = RequestContext( request ) )
```

Comment: not working stilldef login(request):
    template = "../templates/admin/login.html"
    data = {
        }
    user = auth.authenticate(username='aa', password='bb')
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/login/index/")

    return render_to_response( template, data, 
                               context_instance = RequestContext( request ) )

Comment: Oh, right. You are authenticating your user with hard coded values, so IF the user 'aa' has password 'bb', you will get the redirect as you designed. Now, it's time to pull username and password from request.POST.