# django user authentication how to do?

Tags: django, authentication

my question is when i click to submit button in my  login page it will not check the entered username and password  correctely whether the username and password matches.even if i  leave blank my username and password field and click submit button it redirect to index page which i defined in html code(action) as below:

now i want when i enter username=aa ,password=bb then only it redirect to index page otherwise stay in login page if username password not correct or not entered.
actually im new to django and even i used authenticate(...something... )as below:

don't knw the exact way to do this.

```
def login(request):
    template = "../templates/admin/login.html"
    data ={
        }

    user = auth.authenticate(username='aa', password='bb')
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
       auth.login(request, user)
    return render_to_response( template, data, 
                               context_instance = RequestContext( request ) )

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')


<form id="FormName11" action="/index/" method="post" class="prettyformlogin" name="FormName11">
{% csrf_token %}

<table width='448' border='0' cellspacing='2' cellpadding='0'>
<tr> 
    <td><b>Username</b></td>
    <td><input id='username' type='text' name='username'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Password</b></td>
    <td><input id='password' type='password' name='password'>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Login'></td>
</tr>
```

thanx in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [django page redirect on success login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473050/django-page-redirect-on-success-login)

Comment: This is now the *fourth* time you have asked this question. Stop doing that. And learn how to format your pasted code.

Comment: actually im not getting how to do this?plz help.

Comment: Altering/Updating you question will trow it on the wall again. So instead of c/p questions just please update one until you'll get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use login?

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login

Is the user definitely exist? Why not try putting some 'print' to see what's going on?

Comment: actually i want that username and password is set manually so that when i click submit button it will firstly match username and password and then redirect to index page and i tried above code but not getting success

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? If you want a user to be able to login and then to redirect the index page, login() will achieve that. You can specify where you want to redirect to after a successful login by settings LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in your settings file.

Answer (score 0):

> my question is when i click to submit
>   button in my login page it will not
>   check the entered username and
>   password correctely whether the
>   username and password matches.even if
>   i leave blank my username and password
>   field and click submit button it
>   redirect to index page which i defined
>   in html code(action) as below:

If i'm looking at this correctly. You never even get the values from the form... You just are checking explicitly defined username='aa' and password='bb'

in your views.py

```
user = auth.authenticate(username='aa', password='bb')
```

You need to look at getting the submitted data:

```
def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    # etc...
```